# SQL Code to list a range of products

Tags: sql, sorting, filter, ms-access-2013

I have the following line of code, which prompts the user to select the `ProductID` that he/she wants to display:

```
where TableName.ProductID=[Enter ProductID:]
```

What would be the command or logic for a range of product IDs, which are unrelated?
For example: Ideally the user would input `ProductID1`, `ProductID2` and `ProductID10`

Thank  you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` operator to pass list of values to a column

```
Where TableName.ProductID in ( ProductID1,ProductID2,ProductID3..)
```

Comment: @Indian- this would assume I know ahead of time which products the user would like to see. What if the user will be making up his/her mind as he/she goes?

Comment: What do you meant by *What if the user will be making up his/her mind as he/she goes?*

Comment: when running the query, the user may decide to see data for ProductID1, ProductID2, ProductID3.  Or the user may want to see data for ProductID6, ProductID7, ProductID8. The [Enter ProductID:] provides this flexibility, but only for one product. How would I provide this flexibility for the user to select a list of products, which I would not know ahead of time?

Answer (score 0):

try these

```
where TableName.ProductID in ([Enter ProductID1],[Enter ProductID2],[Enter ProductID10])


where TableName.ProductID between ([Enter ProductID1][Enter ProductID2],[Enter ProductID10])
```

Comment: this would limit the user to the predefined list of 3 ProductsIDs, which I think the user should select. I want to leave it open for the user to select which ProductIDs he/she wants to be displayed.

Comment: for that u need to use checkboxlist form frontend and send the selected value to the database using string builder and append the  value to and send to database as parameter. in database these values will be appended to your query and the desired result will be achived

Comment: can you provide a link for a tutorial how it's done?

Comment: it is simple but the problem with this solution is that when product ids increase in number then the check box list will have all the ids which are in database . so will recommend listbox control. the explanation is in other comment

Comment: drag drop list box and populate it with ids from database. Then in list box set  ' SelectionMode="Multiple" ' . Now create  a filter like  string filter = Getfilter();  now method definition privite sting Getfilter()

Answer (score 0):

step 1 :-

```
string filter = GetFIlter(); 


private string GetFIlter()
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
    if (listbox.SelectedValue != "")
    {
            string value = "";
            foreach (ListItem li in listbox.Items)
            {
                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    value = value + li.Value + ",";
                }
            }

            value = value.TrimEnd(',');
            stringBuilder.Append("where TableName.ProductID in(" + value + ")");
        }
return stringBuilder.ToString().Trim();
    }
```

step 2 :-
then pass filter to the database and append the filter to the query as
urQuery +@filter (filter comming from frontend)

Comment: is the code a query or code builder?; Here's what I did by steps: (1) Created a list box; (2) Row source -> SQL query to list the products I want to be listed in the list box; (3) On click -> macro is run; (4) I chose the Multi Select option and the following VBA code :

Comment: this code will generate sql filter that will be appended to ur original query

Comment: where should I insert it?

Comment: u can raise button event then in that event start from step 1  and then send filter to database i.e to procedure and apend to query eg         @filter        nvarchar(max)  and the ur query like select * from urtable +@filter ... filter will contain the condition that we added from front end.. check code

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub List0_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
   Dim varItem As Variant
   Dim strCriteria As String
   Dim strSQL As String
   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryMultiSelect")
   For Each varItem In Me!lstProduct.ItemsSelected
      strCriteria = strCriteria & ",'" & Me!lstProduct.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
   Next varItem
   If Len(strCriteria) = 0 Then
      MsgBox "You did not select anything from the list" _
             , vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
      Exit Sub
   End If
   strCriteria = Right(strCriteria, Len(strCriteria) - 1)
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM ProductTable " & _
            "WHERE ProductTable.ID IN(" & strCriteria & ");"
   qdf.SQL = strSQL
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMultiSelect"
   Set db = Nothing
   Set qdf = Nothing
End Sub
```